# How to read csv file in R where some values contain the percent symbol (%)

Tags: r, csv

**Is there a clean/automatic way to convert CSV values formatted with as percents (with trailing `%` symbol) in R?**

Here is some example data:

```
actual,simulated,percent error
2.1496,8.6066,-300%
0.9170,8.0266,-775%
7.9406,0.2152,97%
4.9637,3.5237,29%
```

Which can be read using:

```
junk = read.csv("Example.csv")
```

But all of the % columns are read as strings and converted to factors:

```
> str(junk)
 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ actual       : num  2.15 0.917 7.941 4.964
 $ simulated    : num  8.607 8.027 0.215 3.524
 $ percent.error: Factor w/ 4 levels "-300%","-775%",..: 1 2 4 3
```

but I would like them to be numeric values.

Is there an additional parameter for read.csv? Is there a way to easily post process the needed columns to convert to numeric values? Other solutions?

*Note: of course in this example I could simply recompute the values, but in my real application with a larger data file this is not practical.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no "percentage" type in R. So you need to do some post-processing:

```
DF <- read.table(text="actual,simulated,percent error
2.1496,8.6066,-300%
0.9170,8.0266,-775%
7.9406,0.2152,97%
4.9637,3.5237,29%", sep=",", header=TRUE)

DF[,3] <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "",DF[,3]))/100

#  actual simulated percent.error
#1 2.1496    8.6066         -3.00
#2 0.9170    8.0266         -7.75
#3 7.9406    0.2152          0.97
#4 4.9637    3.5237          0.29
```

Comment: For performance reasons I would suggest `as.numeric(sub("%", "",DF[[3]],fixed=TRUE))` (`sub` for searching only one occurrence, `fixed=TRUE` to search for exact pattern not for regular expression, `DF[[3]]` is way more efficient than `DF[,3]`).

Comment: @Marek It would be interesting to know how big the data needs to be before that makes a perceptible difference.

Comment: `[[` probably won't give a relevant performance gain over `[` if not applied repeatedly.

Comment: @hadley My suggestion take half of the time of the original code. For 100k rows it's diffrence 0.5sec vs 1sec. Not very much, but if he do it for larger set, more columns, on daily basis then it's could save nociteable time.

Comment: @Marek If that was a regular task with bigger sized data I would suggest removing the `%` using sed. However, it's generally not a good idea to store data with a unit in the values. Normally it's Excel users that come up with stuff like this and their data is not often very big. If someone regulary provided me with data containing `%` values I would educate them to change that on their side of the workflow.

Comment: If you wanted to treat % "correctly", you could always go for `as.numeric(sub("%", "e-2",DF[[3]],fixed=TRUE))` - % is really just a short hand for 'divide by 100', and '5%' now becomes '5e-2'.  Pedantic perhaps, but no need for the external divide by 100 then.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as Roland's solution except using the `stringr` package. When working with strings I'd recommend it though as the interface is more intuitive.

```
library(stringr)
d <- str_replace(junk$percent.error, pattern="%", "")
junk$percent.error <- as.numeric(d)/100
```

Comment: Seems this might also need the /100?

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` you can achieve it as

```
a <- fread("file.csv")[,`percent error` := as.numeric(sub('%', '', `percent error`))/100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse has multiple ways of solving such issues. You can use the parse_number() specification which will strip a number off any symbols, text etc.:

```
sample_data = "actual,simulated,percent error\n 2.1496,8.6066,-300%\n 0.9170,8.0266,-775%\n7.9406,0.2152,97%\n4.9637,3.5237,29%"
DF <- read_csv(sample_data,col_types = cols(`percent error`= col_number()))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# actual   simulated `percent error`
# <chr>        <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 2.1496     8.61           -300  
# 2 + 0.9170     8.03           -775 
# 3 + 7.9406     0.215            97.0
# 4 + 4.9637     3.52             29.0
```